# Cannot locate counters implemented from micrometer library in Datadog Metrics Explorer

Tags: datadog, micrometer

I’ve tried creating a couple metrics called `heartBeatExecutionCounter` and `heartBeatSuccessCounter` using the micrometer integration with Datadog (see https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/datadog).

However, I can’t find the counters in the metrics explorer I created when searching for `ep_heartbeat_job_success_count` or `ep_heartbeat_job_execution_count` as they're defined in their respective `builder`s. Any idea where I went wrong in my implementation?

#### EDIT

I checked my logs and do see the that I am failing to send metrics to datadog

```
2022-12-17 23:40:00,006  WARN [datadog-metrics-publisher] (DatadogMeterRegistry.java:149) - failed to send metrics to datadog
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/common/util/StringUtils
    at io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogNamingConvention.name(DatadogNamingConvention.java:62) ~[micrometer-registry-datadog-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Meter$Id.getConventionName(Meter.java:319) ~[micrometer-core-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getConventionName(MeterRegistry.java:253) ~[micrometer-core-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
    at io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry.writeMetric(DatadogMeterRegistry.java:254) ~[micrometer-registry-datadog-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry.lambda$writeMeter$12(DatadogMeterRegistry.java:212) ~[micrometer-registry-datadog-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4747) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4755) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList$2.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry.publish(DatadogMeterRegistry.java:138) ~[micrometer-registry-datadog-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry.publishSafely(PushMeterRegistry.java:52) ~[micrometer-core-1.8.4.jar:1.8.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
```

## Implementation

```java
private MeterRegistry registry = DatadogUtils.getRegistry();
 
// Create a Counter to track the number of successful executions
private Counter heartBeatSuccessCounter = Counter.builder("ep_heartbeat_job_success_count")
        .description("Number of successful executions of the EpHeartBeatJob")
        .register(registry);

// Create a Counter to track the number of executions
private Counter heartBeatExecutionCounter = Counter.builder("ep_heartbeat_job_execution_count")
        .description("Number of executions of the EpHeartBeatJob")
        .register(registry);
```

And then I increment them here:

```java
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        // Increment the counter to track the number of executions
        heartBeatExecutionCounter.increment();
        try {
            log.info("Job ** {} ** starting @ {}", context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName(), context.getFireTime());
            if (isLocalEnv()) {
                epHeartBeatService.startTask();
            } else {
                outageMillisPerDay += epHighAvailablityService.startTask();
                log.info("Accumulated outage = {} milliseconds", outageMillisPerDay);

                calendar.setTime(context.getFireTime());
                if (outageMillisPerDay > OUTAGE_MILLIS_ALLOWED_PER_WEEK) {
                    //&& calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==0) {
                    throw new Exception("Actual outage exceeded allowable outage");
                }
            }

            // Increment the counter to track the number of successful executions
            heartBeatSuccessCounter.increment();

            log.info("Job ** {} ** completed.  Next job scheduled @ {}", context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName(), context.getNextFireTime());
            log.info("====================================================");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Datadog Utils class that is supposed to provide the registry

```java
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Clock;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogConfig;
import io.micrometer.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry;

public class DatadogUtils {

    private static DatadogConfig config = new DatadogConfig() {
        @Override
        public String apiKey() {
            return "my_key";
        }

        @Override
        public String get(String key) {return null;};
    };

    private static final MeterRegistry registry = new DatadogMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);

    public static MeterRegistry getRegistry() {
        return registry;
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:latest.release'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was missing the `micrometer-core` library.

```java
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:latest.release'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:latest.release'
}
```